# Pygame: Alien Invasion Ship Image

Tags: python, image, pygame, load, traceback

Hi I am currently trying to create space invasion from chapter 12 in Python Crash Course. However I am stuck when trying to add the ship image to the game. Here is the code for Alien Invasion:

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
class AlienInvasion:
#Overall class to manage game assests and behavior

    def __init__(self):
        #Initialize the game and create game resources
        pygame.init()
        self.settings=Settings()
    
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')

       self.Ship=Ship(self)



    def run_game(self):
        # Start the main loop for the game
        while True:
           #Watch for keyboard and mouse events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                 if event.type==pygame.QUIT  :
                     sys.exit()
            #Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
             self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)

            self.Ship.blitme()
            #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__=='__main__':
#Make a game instance, and run the game.
ai=AlienInvasion()
ai.run_game()
```

Ship Code:

```
import pygame


 class Ship:
     #A class to manage the ship
     def __init__(self, ai_game):
       #Initialize the ship and set its starting position
       self.screen=ai_game.screen
       self.screen_rect=ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        #Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image=pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()

        #start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom=self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        #Draw the ship at its current location
        self.scren.bilt(self.image, self.rect)
```

When trying to run it i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/rico3/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Scripts/Alien Invasion/Alien_Invaders.py", line 39, in <module>
 ai=AlienInvasion()
 File "c:/Users/rico3/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Scripts/Alien Invasion/Alien_Invaders.py", line 19, in __init__
self.Ship=Ship(self)
File "c:\Users\rico3\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Scripts\Alien Invasion\ship.py", line 12, in __init__
self.image=pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
pygame.error: Couldn't open images/ship.bmp
```

The images folder is in the same folder as the Alien Invasion file yet it still cant seem to find the ship file.

Comment: How do you launch the game? It's not enough that images folder is in the same folder as the Alien Invasion file. You also need to set the current directory of the process to be same as Alien Invasion file. To check what is the current directory add: `import os; print(os.getcwd())` right before you call `pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')` and see if the printed value matches your expectation.

Comment: It could be an issue with your directory separator. You can check your OS separator with `import os` and `print(os.sep)`. If your separator is a backslash, then you'll have to edit your file-path accordingly, escaping the backslash as well.

Comment: I'm launching the game in VS code terminal and also using the Alien Invasion file. The directory on Ship and Alien invasion match, but I'm still getting the couldn't open error.

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up a lot, so I'll aim for a canonical answer.

Basically the code is trying to load a file, but it is *assuming* it's running in the same directory as the files it needs.  This problem isn't limited to Python or PyGame, it's a general programming problem.  It becomes more of a problem when PyGame programs are packed into executables, which are unpacked to *who-knows-where* at runtime.

So, what can you do?  First, don't assume anything.  On startup, "feel around" the environment - work out where the code is running from.

Your current directory is available from the `os` module:

```
import os
print( "Running in directory: " + os.getcwd() )
```

If I run this script from different locations, notice the different result:

```
tmp> python3 ~/Code/Python/PyGame/working_dir.py
Running in directory: /tmp
```

And from the same directory:

```
PyGame> python3 ./working_dir.py 
Running in directory: /home/kingsley/Code/Python/PyGame
```

In your case, it's like the first output - the current directory is not the same as where your `images/` are.  So in this case, you can use the `os.path` module `diranme()` and `realpath()` functions to determine the full path to your script.  This works well because it's the same no matter what directory the script is launched from.

```
import os
import os.path

exe_location = os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath( __file__ ) )

print( "Running in directory: " + os.getcwd() ) 
print( "Running script from:  " + exe_location )
```

Giving:

```
tmp> python3 ~/Code/Python/PyGame/working_dir.py
Running in directory: /tmp
Running script from:  /home/kingsley/Code/Python/PyGame
```

Now this path can be used as the offset for your images directory.  This brings me to my next point.  *Don't* do things like:

```
path = exe_location + "\\" + images_dir + "\\" + subdir1  # <-- WRONG!
```

Your code will fail on any system that doesn't use the same directory separators as you.  Use the `os.path` module function `join()`.  It knows the correct path-separator for the local system, and handles any clean-up of double separators and the like, correctly.

```
path = os.path.join( exe_location, images_dir, subdir1 )  # <-- PERFECT!
```

So in your code:

```
import os.path

# [...]

if __name__=='__main__':
    exe_location = os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath( __file__ ) )
```

Then use `exe_location` as a global, or pass it into your class constructors as a parameter.  When loading images (or sounds, or fonts, etc.), calculate the correct *absolute* path with `os.path.join()`:

```
class Ship:
    #A class to manage the ship
    def __init__( self, ai_game, install_path ):
        #Initialize the ship and set its starting position
        [ ... ]

        #Load the ship image and get its rect.
        filename = os.path.join( install_path, "images", "ship.bmp" )
        self.image=pygame.image.load( filename )
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
```

You may also want to be careful of the alphabetical case of your directory and file names.  On some file systems, "Images/" is not the same as "images/".  Use what ever case you want, but keep it exact.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, did you make a directory "images" containing ship.bmp and include it in the main project folder, as shown in the screenshots.

vscode:

[image: screen shot from vscode]

terminal:

[image: screen shot from terminal]

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck on this, for the stupidest of reasons. I got the idea that the pygame.image.load statement would access the image from pygame's own library. In fact, it loads from a file which the user provides and places in the directory where the code is looking.

Eric Matthes explains, on p.233 of the 2nd edition, that the spaceship bitmap is in the online resources for the book at https://nostarch.com/pythoncrashcourse2e/
Scroll down to the bottom of the page, and click on "click here for the second edition". Follow through to the resources for chapter 12.